# MS Access Unspecified parameter even though all IS specified

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

MS Access 2010 brings an error (Enter Parameter value) when I try to perform the following very simple Union query:

```
SELECT 
    [1_Toyota_2013_mit_PFC_2].[FC-Teile-Nr] 
FROM 1_Toyota_2013_mit_PFC_2

UNION 

SELECT 
    [1_Toyota_2013_ohne_PFC_2].[FC-Teile-Nr] 
FROM 1_Toyota_2013_ohne_PFC_2;
```

Everything is specified... I understand that having "-" in the names forces me to use brackets. I am doing that, but it still causes an error. If I simply press OK, then I do get the correct result. But I'd like to have the error not pop up.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: try to wrap table names in FROM part with brackets.

Comment: Hi 4dmonster, I added the brackets. Still the same problem.

Comment: Are [1_Toyota_2013_mit_PFC_2] and [1_Toyota_2013_ohne_PFC_2] table or queries? If queries - Do they ask parameter?

Comment: What is the name of unspecified parameter?

Comment: They are queries. Thanks for the hint! When I open up the `code1_Toyota_2013_ohne_PFC_2` it brings the same message. Can't figure out why though... all looks fine to me there as well... and it's not even an SQL query that I wrote. Just the normal Access one.

Comment: The name of the parameter is: `1_Toyota_2013_ohne_PFC_1.Deaktivieren`. Deaktiveren being german for deactivate... you probably would have guessed that, but just in case.

Comment: [1_Toyota_2013_ohne_PFC_2] asks for [1_Toyota_2013_ohne_PFC_1.Deaktivieren] ? Then correct 1_Toyota_2013_ohne_PFC_1.Deaktivieren to 1_Toyota_2013_ohne_PFC_2.Deaktivieren

Comment: 4dmonster: I found the problem thanks to your probing questions! Thanks! See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query was based on two sub queries. The unspecified parameter was a calculated field in one of the sub queries that I had created. After creating the field, I subsequently changed the name of one of the tables, and while Access updated all the other query fields, it did not ofcourse update my manually created calculation.

Thanks for the probing questions that led me to the answer 4dmonster!